# What exactly is causing the grid to not show? JAVA SWING

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to create a simple minesweeper for my AP CS project. The field class generates the field or the board of the game. The JFrame is the entire window. And the JPanel is the grid. The Tile class is the class I created that extends JButton and represents 1 box on the JPanel grid. But when I set both JPanel + JFrame to visible the result is an empty window. No grids no nothing. Also the Tile array holds the tile in an array so I can traverse it later to calc number of bombs, etc. The JPanel is the GUI representation of the grid.

Field.java:

```java
public class Field extends JFrame {

    private JPanel panel;
    private Tile[][] field;
    private int numRows, numCols;
    private int numMines;
            
    public Field(int numRows, int numCols, int numMines) {
        super("MineSweeper");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(540, 600);
        
        
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(numRows, numCols));
        panel.setSize(540, 540);
        panel.setVisible(true);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(numRows, numCols));
        addTiles();
        setContentPane(panel);
        
        setVisible(true);
        panel.setVisible(true);
   }
public void addTiles() {
        for(int y=0; y<numRows; y++) {
            for(int x=0; x<numCols; x++) {  
                Tile t = new Tile(x, y);
                panel.add(t);
                field[y][x] = t;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tile.java:

```java
public class Tile extends JButton {

    private int xPos, yPos;
    private int numMinesAround;
    private boolean isMine, isFlagged;
    
    public Tile(int xPos, int yPos) {
        this.xPos = xPos;
        this.yPos = yPos;
        
        this.numMinesAround = 0;
        
        this.isMine = false;
        this.isFlagged = false;
    }
}
```

What exactly is causing the program to create a blank window with no grids and stuff?

Comment: We're missing the most relevant method: what does `addTiles` do?

Comment: @JoachimSauer Oop! Imma add it now

Comment: Please remove the image which is not relevant to the original question. The Q&A should have value for future users.

Comment: Before posting code in future, please copy/paste it into a new package / project in the IDE, compile and run it, and test it is actually a [mre]. It still isn't, for a variety of reasons. Don't forget that the people here only have an academic interest in solving the problem. Make it easy for them to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some fields are not initialized. Add

```
    this.numRows = numRows; this.numCols = numCols;
    field = new Tile[numRows][numCols];
```

Comment: I updated the class, but still not working :(

Comment: Did you make sure to set `this.numRows` and `this.numCols` **before** calling `addTiles`?

Comment: Post the updated code

Comment: Now I'm getting some tiles but the window looks off

Comment: I'll show the image in post

Comment: You can test it online:  https://repl.it/@c0derrepo/PrizeQuarrelsomeBackups#Main.java

Comment: For other problems have a new post. Changing the question in the post makes answers irrelevant.